# How long can this motor run?

Tags: motor, watts

If I have a 48v 20Ah 1000w lithium ion battery, how long could it continually run a 48v 33Amp 2000w motor?

Also, how big of a battery would I need to have it run for 45mins at least?

Comment: Probably 20 mins or even less

Comment: Less time than a simple calculation would suggest.  For one thing, normal AH ratings on Lead-Acid batteries are usually specified for a discharge over a 20 Hour time period.  Actual battery capacity degrades significantly if you attempt to discharge the battery in a very short time period.

Comment: I am assuming a Lead-Acid battery based on your voltage and AH specification.

Comment: Oh shoot. I forgot to mention that it's a lithium ion battery

Comment: What's the deal with the battery being rated for a "1000w" what is the its C rating (maximum current)? If it is a LiPo and no conversion/other circuits are being used you should probably get 90% of the capacity or so, resulting in (20Ah/33A)*90% (about 35 minutes).

Comment: Also keep in mind the start current of the motor .. yikes

Comment: @jDAQ Yeah. That 1000W is meaningless unless it is implying the battery is only rated for 1C, which seems unlikely since it is so low. 48V x 20Ah does not equal 1000W because volts x Amp-hours is not Watts. Also, a 48V, 33A 2000W motor makes no sense either since 48V x 33A is not 2000W. None of the Watt ratings provided make sense.

Comment: @jDAQ, the battery's instantaneous Maximum Discharge Current is  90A, and the Rated Discharge Current is 30A

Comment: Would the fact that the motor takes in 33A and the battery's rated discharge current is 30A be a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clarify what comments are evoking and answer your questions :

1. The battery
   A true 20Ah battery will be able to provide 20A during 1h, 40A during 30min or 10A during 2h. Ok that's obvious. You must be aware of the capacity derating that occurs on high discharge currents so you won't be able to get the full capacity. Moreover some Chinese accus capacity are highly overestimated (marketing reasons). Sometimes a factor of 2 must be applied. Depending on the seller seriosity, the 1000W specifies:

   - either the maximum and reasonable power output. For a 48V battery this means you won't be able or shouldn't get more current than 1000W/48V = about 21A.
   - or I will suggest that it s an eroneous but common unit simplification that take the capacity 20Ah times the voltage 48V which approximately is equal to 1000Wh. And h is removed. It is common to see incoherent units in some product datasheet.
2. The motor
   Power mentioned is commonly overestimated for marketing reasons. So it must be approximately the maximum power output under specific conditions (optimal speed, maybe higher than 48V voltage, or even for the numerical model of the motor, and so on). For having spent much time looking for motor references on the internet, you always must be careful with announced motor performances.

To answer your questions : 
You will be able to run it an amount of time that depends on the motor charge (how much current the charge will draw) and the efficiency of your control (for a brushless motor for instance). A BLDC motor with a 80% efficiency functional point and an output power of 200W (speed in rad/s times torque in N.m) will drive 200/0,8=250W electrical power. With a 48V battery it means an average current of 250/48=5,2A. So your battery will works less than 4h. Take some margin because of what I explained in 1.
Apply this to your application, that's it.

Comment: Wait so if the motor is 80% efficient (I'm not sure about this) and the rpm is ~3000 (so ~314 rad/s) and the torque is 4N.m, then the output power is 3000×4 = 12,000w, so 12,000/80% = 15,000w, and 15,000w/48v = 312.5A, so it runs 20Ah/312.5A = 3.84mins?! This can't be right. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Output power is 314*4 and not 3000*4. It means 1256/0,8=1570W. So current is about 33A and it could run 36min.

Comment: Ah, that make much more sense. Thanks for finding my stupid mistake

Comment: Also--I commented this above, but would the fact that the motor takes in 33A and the battery's rated discharge current is 30A be a problem?

Comment: That's no ideal and this will affect the longevity of the battery and its capacity too. I would say that capacity will be roughly 80% at a 1,5C discharge (1,5C means 1,5*20A(h)=30A) but get the spec to be more precise. Manufacturer should be able to provide discharge curves at different rates.

Comment: I see. Thanks for your help